# Oracle Optimizer Awkwardly Doesn't Prefer to Use Index

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, query-performance

I'm joining a table with itself but although I expect this operation to use index, it seems it doesn't. There are 1 million records on the table(`MY_TABLE`) and the query I run is executing on about 10 thousand records.(So it is lower than %1 of whole table.)

**Test Case:**

```
explain plan for
SELECT *
  FROM SCHM.MY_TABLE A1, SCHM.MY_TABLE A2
 WHERE     (A1.K_ID = '123abc')
       AND A1.HDT = A2.HDT
       AND A2.C_DATE BETWEEN A1.SYSDATE - 0.0004 
                           AND A1.SYSDATE + 0.0004 
       AND A1.GKID = A2.GKID;


Plan hash value: 1210306805

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                             | Name             | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                      |                  |     3 |    81 |    28   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  FILTER                               |                  |       |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN                           |                  |     3 |    81 |    28   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| MY_TABLE          |     3 |    45 |     7   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | IX_MY_TABLE_C_DATE |     3 |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| MY_TABLE          |    17 |   204 |    21   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | IX_MY_TABLE_K_ID |    17 |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(SYSDATE@!+0.00004>=SYSDATE@!-0.00004)
   2 - access("A1"."HDT"="A2"."HDT" AND 
              "A1"."GKID"="A2"."GKID")
   4 - access("A2"."C_DATE">=SYSDATE@!-0.00004 AND 
              "A2"."C_DATE"<=SYSDATE@!+0.00004)
   6 - access("A1"."K_ID"=U'123abc')
```

In the above statement, it can be seen that the index on C_DATE is used.

However, in the below statement, the index on C_DATE is not used. So, the query runs really slow.

**Real Case:**

```
explain plan for
SELECT *
  FROM SCHM.MY_TABLE A1, SCHM.MY_TABLE A2
 WHERE     (A1.K_ID = '123abc')
       AND A1.HDT = A2.HDT
       AND A2.C_DATE BETWEEN A1.C_DATE - 0.0004 
                           AND A1.C_DATE + 0.0004 
       AND A1.GKID = A2.GKID;


Plan hash value: 1063167343

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                             | Name             | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                      |                  |  4187K|   998M|  6549K  (1)| 00:04:16 |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN                            |                  |  4187K|   998M|  6549K  (1)| 00:04:16 |
|   2 |   JOIN FILTER CREATE                  | :BF0000          |    17 |  2125 |    21   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| MY_TABLE          |    17 |  2125 |    21   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | IX_MY_TABLE_K_ID |    17 |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |   JOIN FILTER USE                     | :BF0000          |  1429M|   166G|  6546K  (1)| 00:04:16 |
|*  6 |    TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL          | MY_TABLE          |  1429M|   166G|  6546K  (1)| 00:04:16 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access(A1.HDT=A2.HDT AND 
              A1.GKID=A2.GKID)
       filter(A2.C_DATE>=INTERNAL_FUNCTION(A1.C_DATE)-0.00004 AND 
              A2.C_DATE<=INTERNAL_FUNCTION(A1.C_DATE)+0.00004)
   4 - access(A1.K_ID=U'123abc')
   6 - storage(SYS_OP_BLOOM_FILTER(:BF0000,A2.HDT,A2.HDT))
       filter(SYS_OP_BLOOM_FILTER(:BF0000,A2.HDT,A2.HDT))
```

If I use the hint `/*+index(A2,IX_MY_TABLE_C_DATE )*/`, everthing is fine, the index is used and the query runs fast as I want.

The query in the real case cannot be changed because it is created by application.

```
Index Information:
K_ID, not unique, position 1
HDT, not unique, position 1
C_DATE, not unique, position 1
ID Unique and Primary Key, position 1
```

What do I have to change in order the query in the real case to use index?

Comment: Please include the indexes that exist on the table, and the primary key.

Comment: I add index and PK information.

Comment: I just realized. Do you really have a column named "SYSDATE"? According to the plan of the first query, on note #4 it's comparing against SYSDATE (the date on the database), not a column on A2. This is much faster than a JOIN.

Comment: I haven't column named SYSDATE. in search of  sysdate + 0.0004 and sysdate - 0.0004  range.

Comment: Have you recently updated the stats for the table?

Comment: Yes, analyzes are actual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the second query is slower since it's quite different from the first one. It has an extra join between tables:

```
AND A2.C_DATE BETWEEN A1.C_DATE - 0.0004 
                  AND A1.C_DATE + 0.0004
```

and on a million rows this takes a toll.

The first query doesn't have this join condition and both tables are:

- Filtered first. This is fast using indexes: only 3 rows and 17 rows.
- Joining them second. Joining 3 and 17 rows doesn't take any time.

The second query needs to perform:

- A huge (hash) join first, that returns probably 100K+ rows.
- A filtering later.

This is way slower.

I suggest adding the following indexes, and try again:

```
create index ix_1 (k_id);
create index ix_2 (hdt, gkid, c_date);
```

Comment: But if I run second query(real case) with index hint on c_date, it returns only 11 rows.

Comment: You may see only 11 rows returned (that correspond to ID=0 on the plan). However, internally the HASH join need to assemble 100K+ rows in memory before filtering them (ID=6 on the plan). It's a lot of work.

Comment: I can crate indexes you suggest. But I want to draw attention gkid can be only 2 type and hdt can be only 150 diffrent type. So if you suggest still I will create indexes as you defined.

Comment: Yes, since hst is in first place in the index, it will filter out by 150 right away. This is a good first column for an index.

Comment: with index hint execution time 219 msecs

Comment: That's looks like way faster!

Comment: I try now and I will inform you

Comment: I created index with parallel execution then altered it to noparallel. I execute my query yes it uses index. Earlier I created indexes using hdt and c_date but it did not work. Now I create it using hdt , gkid, c_date , It use index and execution is very good. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You have three join criteria (HDT, GKID, C_DATE) and 1 non-join criteria (K_ID) in your self-join. So for me it would seem natural, if the DBMS started with the records matching K_ID and then looked up all matching other records.

For this case I'd suggest the following indexes:

```
create index idx1 on my_table(k_id, hdt, gkid, c_date);
create index idx2 on my_table(hdt, gkid, c_date);
```

If there are just few records per k_id, I am sure that Oracle will use the indexes. If there are many, Oracle may still use the second one for a hash join.

Comment: According to trace file, non-join criteria for (K_ID)  returns only 17 rows. So join criteria for c_date connot to much coupling

Comment: I can crate indexes you suggest. But I want to draw attention gkid can be only 2 type and hdt can be only 150 diffrent type. So if you suggest still I will create indexes as you defined.

Comment: Sounds good. 17 rows can quickly be found and then it's just few rows to join. The indexes seem appropriate. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Just to add, whenever you have a case where you

1. have a slow SQL,
2. have identified a hint that would make it
   faster
3. cannot change the SQL because the source is not available

then this is a perfect case for SQL Plan Baselines.  These let you lock a "good" plan against an existing SQL without touching the SQL statement itself.

The entire series describing SPM is at the links below, but thelinke to "part 4" walks through an exact example of what you want to achieve.

https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/sql-plan-management-part-1-of-4-creating-sql-plan-baselines
https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/sql-plan-management-part-2-of-4-spm-aware-optimizer
https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/sql-plan-management-part-3-of-4:-evolving-sql-plan-baselines
https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/sql-plan-management-part-4-of-4:-user-interfaces-and-other-features